# Eclipse plugin\Java Library to create flow diagrams

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, dfd

I need to create flow diagrams based on specific inputs, using java code, what are best ways\plugins to achieve this.

[image: sample diagram]

something like the above diagram (For sample only it is taken from google images)

Also the diagrams should be editable after generation.

Comment: In Java there are no plugins. there are only libraries

Comment: updated the header. thanks

Comment: You want to generate this with code? Do you want to execute the flow afterwards was well or are you interested in the image only?

Comment: The requirement is something like i have an xml file with nodes and edges and using some library i read the xml and covert it into graphical image with is editable(can change node color based on certain selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) - the industry standard for graphs. It also has Java API (as well as perl, python, ruby etc.), so it possible to use it in Eclipse.

It uses [DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) - a plain text graph description language. Small example:

```
 digraph graphname {
     a -> b -> c;
     b -> d;
 }
```

And the resulting graph:

[image: A directed graph example]

Graphviz provides everything you need to create any kind of graphs. And yes, diagrams are editable.

Graphviz Eclipse plug-in: https://github.com/abstratt/eclipsegraphviz

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like https://github.com/jgraph/draw.io can solve your Problem. It is the sourcecode for https://www.draw.io/ which is a graphical Editor for creating diagrams.

So you can create an XML-File and upload it to your own version of draw.io and create the flowchart. Then you can edit it and save it to varoious file formats.

This is not the perfect answer, but maybe it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc of JDiagram:

> MindFusion.Diagramming for Java Swing (JDiagram for short) is a Java
>   class library that that lets you create and display various types of
>   diagrams and charts. The library includes model classes that describe
>   the structure and appearance of a flow diagram, and view classes that
>   can be integrated into any application that targets the Java Swing
>   framework

here are the examples, of what you can achieve with the library:

http://www.mindfusion.eu/onlinehelp/jdiagram/

There you could browse the tutorials and the doc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this library might fit the bill...

https://eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd